# Trying to stop the MediaRecorder gives me an IllegalStageException

Tags: java, android

When the service starts, I call `startRecording()` from `onStartCommand()`, and when the service ends, `onDestroy()` is called, from which I call `stoprecording()`. But `recorder.stop()` gives me an `IllegalStageException`

```
void startRecording() {
        recordList = new ArrayList<>();
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        recordListString = mSharedPreferences.getString("RecordList", null);
        if(recordListString!=null){
            recordList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(recordListString, ",")));
        }
        currentFormat = Integer.parseInt(mSharedPreferences.getString("PREF_REC_LIST", "1"));
        tempRecNum = mSharedPreferences.getString("TempRecNum", null);
        audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL),0);
        if (error){
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        }else {
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        }
        cleanDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        //recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        /**recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);**/
        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isRecording", true).apply();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (RuntimeException e) {
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
            String tempPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            if(contactExists) {
                boolean err = new File(tempPath + "/" +
                        getContactDisplayNameByNumber(tempRecNum, this)+"___"+
                        tempRecNum+"|__"+recCount+file_exts[currentFormat]).delete();
                recordList.remove(recordList.size()-1);
            }else{
                boolean err = new File(tempPath + "/" +
                        "___"+tempRecNum+"|__"+recCount+file_exts[currentFormat]).delete();
                recordList.remove(recordList.size()-1);
            }
            error = true;
            startRecording();
        }
    }
    private String getFilename() {

        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
        }
        path = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        if(contactExists(this, tempRecNum, getContentResolver())) {
            contactExists = true;
            fileName =  getContactDisplayNameByNumber(tempRecNum, this)+
                    "___"+tempRecNum+"|__"+recCount+file_exts[currentFormat];
            recordList.add(fileName);
            return (path + "/" + fileName);

        }else {
            contactExists = false;
            fileName = "___"+tempRecNum+"|__"+recCount+file_exts[currentFormat];
            recordList.add(fileName);
            return (path + "/" + fileName);
        }
    }



    private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).
                    edit().putBoolean("isRecording", false).apply();
            Toast.makeText(RecorderService.this,
                    "Error: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };



    private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(RecorderService.this,
                    "Warning: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    };

    @Override public void onDestroy(){
        stopRecording();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    void stopRecording(){
        try{
            if (recorder != null) {
                mSharedPreferences.edit().putString("RecordList", TextUtils.join(",", recordList)).apply();
                mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("RecCount", recCount+1).apply();
                recorder.stop();  //This is where the error is thrown.
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
            }
        }catch(RuntimeException stopException){
            stopException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to the `MediaRecorder` documentation, that exception only occurs if `start()` has not yet been called.  Looking at your code, the only way I can see `start()` not being called is if `prepare()` throws an exception one line above.  Have you checked for this?

Comment: Most likely its already stopped by that point.  But posting the full stack trace helps, as usually IllegalStateException gives an error message as well.

Comment: Yes; suspect your onDestroy isn't being called until after the recorder is already stopped and/or partially torn down. Also, see MediaRecorder docs for state diagram: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop

Comment: @pathfinderelite, yes, if `prepare` throws an exception, (which it does, when using  `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` on some phones), I catch it, and call `startRecording()` again, but this time I use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER`. You can see me catch the exception after prepare

Comment: @SMcCrohan, it does get called. I set breakpoints and checked. That's how I initially found out recorder.stop() was where it stopped executing and went into the catch block.

Comment: Right - not questioning that it's being called. Just think other things are happening BEFORE it's called that alter the recorder state such that `.stop()` is not valid.

Comment: @GabeSechan, the stack trace only says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException`. , and points to where this error is occurring -- which is at `record.stop()`. There's nothing more than that.

Comment: @stack Actually, if `prepare` throws an exception, `startRecording` will not get called.  `prepare` throws `IllegalStateException` and `IOException`, both of which you are catching and doing nothing but `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @pathfinderelite, guilty. So the problem is with recoder.start() throwing an illegalstateexception. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Just to make sure, you have added this line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` to the manifest. Don't you?

Comment: @pathfinderelite  Here's the error from the stack trace - ` start failed: -38`

@ChakerMallek, yes, I do.